# Ways to incorporate dynamic update in flash cc

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, adobe

Currently i'm working on a flash game where i want a certain value to appear on the right side when the user types in a value on the left side.

Where the default amount is 0 and when the person types a number, the price(on the right will update accordingly.

Is it possible for this to be achieved?

*The text's fields are all set to dynamic text fields

Picture below,
[image: )]

Comment: you will have to bind changes somehow (by an event handler or publish-subscribe pattern) and update the field when the other field changes (se also MVC in actrionscript for more general application of this concept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but its a little more effort as i see your using the timeline animation.

Easier way to reference everything is to set up a scope of variables that can be accesses anywhere:

In your situation its best to put your whole content movie inside an **Empty** movieClip as a container...

[image]

Now you will have your whole movie inside the MovieClip--

Your Project Structure:

```
Container ---- Price.
          |
          --- Actions.
          |
          --- BTN.
```

[image]

Put your actions on the container layer as now you can set your variables there and create functions to interact with your buttons.. // referencing from my movieClip. As you will not have any scoping issues if you need to go to and from  frames.

Give your text boxes unique names so you can reference them.

You will need to set up Event handlers to respond to your functions ();

Note: Embedd your fonts on export as Dynamic texts boxes may show up empty

**Further more for idea:**
For simplicity you could use an enterframe function and just check if 
textbox.text = "" else--> run your function...
But it will be more appropriate to check weather text box focus or any key press/down to then check the text boxes inputs... depending on the complexity of your application and your understanding on OOP..

Comment: Hi Careen, thanks for your detailed explaination! Real appreciate it, as for the event listeners, i read something about attaching listeners to each of the individual textfields to listen for key press events and hence will set value for the price?